# How to reference a Kivy Canvas in python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

How would I reference a Kivy Canvas for drawing from the python file if the UI is being built in kv, for instance here's my .py:

```
# canvasCallApp.py...

from kivy.app import App

class canvasCallApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvasCallApp().run()
```

And my .kv:

```
# canvasCallApp.kv...

BoxLayout:
    id: left_box
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.6, 0.6, 0.6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: left_box.width - right_box.width        
    BoxLayout:
        width: 200
        id: right_box
        Button:
            text: 'I ma a button'
```

Which produces:

[image]

How would I get to the canvas in the `left_box` for drawing purposes from python ? couldn't figure it out from the docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to change the color or the size of the canvas dynamically,

I recommend using Kivy Properties for it.

Here is the code.

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class RootLayout(BoxLayout):
    canvas_color = ListProperty([0, 1, 1])


class canvasCallApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


kv = Builder.load_string('''
RootLayout:
    id: left_box
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: root.canvas_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Widget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: left_box.width - right_box.width        
    BoxLayout:
        width: 200
        id: right_box
        Button:
            text: 'I ma a button'
''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvasCallApp().run()
```

I also recommend using `RootLayout` which makes it easier to reference a variable from python code by `root.variable_name`.

If you want to change the background of the canvas, you can also change the kivy code to

```
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: root.canvas_color
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: root.image_path
```

in this way, you can import `StringProperty` from `kivy.properties` and apply the same thing. As the value of `image_path` changes, the background automatically changes.

If you want to access canvas directly in order to redraw the canvas, you can use `with canvas`

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

class SomeBoxLayout(BoxLayout)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)  # set the color to red
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.center,
                                  size=(self.width/2.,
                                        self.height/2.))

    def redraw(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 1, 1)  # set the color to blue
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.center,
                                  size=(self.width/2.,
                                        self.height/2.))
```

Note that you should do `canvas.clear()` before you draw something again.

Plus, you can use `with self.canvas.before` or `with self.canvas.after` this way.

Comment: Thank but my goal is to trigger animations, so not sure properties would cut it, was thinking something like ``self.widget.canvas.clear()`` but no luck so far.

Comment: @Keno I have added more codes with some explanations. Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

I opted for ditching the separate kivy language and do it all in python, this requires some nesting of widgets to achieve the correct layout, and more importantly creating, binding and initializing a widget/canvas object we can later refer to:

```
# canvasTest.py...

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from random import random as r


class rootCanvas(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rootCanvas, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(r(), 1, 1, mode='hsv')
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect)
        self.bind(size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = (self.size[0], self.size[1])

    def change_color(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(r(), 1, 1, mode='hsv')
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)


class canvasTest(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout()
        sideBar = BoxLayout(size=(200, 100), size_hint=(None, 1))
        widget = rootCanvas()
        root.add_widget(widget)
        btn_1 = Button(
            text='Change Canvas Color',
            width=200,
            on_press=widget.change_color)
        sideBar.add_widget(btn_1)
        root.add_widget(sideBar)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvasTest().run()
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: I also prefer doing things in code, but it can be tricky converting from `.kv` declarations, as the docs tend to just use `.kv`. How do you make the conversion? Trial-and-error, or are there any documents/tutorials that are more program-oriented?